# CRUD Laravel 5.2, The function should be delete, but it give me add

Tags: php, function, laravel, routes, laravel-5

i'm new in Laravel especially Laravel 5.2, and I've following the CRUD tutorial from [here](http://georgehk.blogspot.co.id/2015/04/crud-operations-in-laravel-5-with-mysql.html).

Everything is okay, but I'm stuck in the delete function.

```
 {!! Form::model($book, ['_method' => 'DELETE', 'action' => ['BookController@destroy', $book->id]]) !!}
 {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

And I use the

```
Route::resource('books','BookController');
```

Here the controller:

```
 public function destroy($id)
{
    $book= Book::find($id)
    ->delete();
    return "deleted";
}
```

When I run the

> php artisan route:list

It's listed name (i think the name who is the main problem):

```
+--------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                | Name          | Action                                          | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                  |               | Closure                                         | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | books              | books.index   | App\Http\Controllers\BookController@index       | web        |
|        | POST      | books              | books.store   | App\Http\Controllers\BookController@store       | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | books/create       | books.create  | App\Http\Controllers\BookController@create      | web        |
|        | DELETE    | books/{books}      | books.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\BookController@destroy     | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | books/{books}      | books.update  | App\Http\Controllers\BookController@update      | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | books/{books}      | books.show    | App\Http\Controllers\BookController@show        | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | books/{books}/edit | books.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\BookController@edit        | web        |
|        | DELETE    | books/{id}         | books.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\BookController@destroy     | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | user               |               | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@showProfile | web        |
+--------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

There's NO ERROR, but the function isn't right. They should be deleted the book, but they are not. They adding the blank row to mysql.

EDITED:
If you get the same error with me:
1. Check if the `id` same with your primary key.
2. Makes sure your id who listed in coding is same with the database.
3. And, check out the answer who work for me below, thanks a lot guys!

Comment: sorry for my bad grammar. I've ask this to my local friends before, but no one of them can solve this well (or maybe i'm just to noob for this).

Comment: Your linked tutorial seems to be using `method => ...` instead of `_method => ...` is that a typo?

Comment: When i used the method, it's came error 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException', i search it that because the delete method isn't allowed, so I manipulate it with _method. It's works, but not with the function.

Comment: So it's a typo in the tutorial then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine.

Can i see your table in database? Maybe you're using another name to create the primary key in your table. If it's true, then you have to add this code on the top of your Book Model.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'your-column-name';
```

Hope it will works.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your code is fine, just need to change `action` of form. You registered your controller as resource, so You can access it by route name.

Also your `_method` attribute is not valid, it should be named `method`.

Change this line `{!! Form::model($book, ['_method' => 'DELETE', 'action' => ['BookController@destroy', $book->id]]) !!}`

To:  `{!! Form::model($book, ['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['books.destroy', $book->id]]) !!}`

Comment: Thanks for your response. It came error whenever i use method : `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

Comment: Can You attach your view here?

Comment: I think codeshare.io would be better. Here we are: [link](https://codeshare.io/LZzEq)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
{!! Form::model ($book, array('method' => 'Delete', 'route' => array('books.destroy', $book->id))) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

You should use `method` instead of `_method`. In the output HTML you'll get `_method`.

Also, it's better to use routes for better maintainability.

**Update**

Try to use `Book::destroy($id)` and not `delete()` in your controller.

Comment: It's came error: `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` whenever i use the `method`

Comment: Thanks for your response anyway hehe

Comment: Check you table. Maybe you've deleted book and now `$books` is empty and you're getting an error when you're trying to interate `$books` in your view.

Comment: Still adding the row with null value, are you following the tutorial linked above? And what the laravel version that you use?

Comment: Did you check books table? Is it empty?

Comment: No, it's filled, and I can call it, I mean the read function work well.

Comment: You gave link to a tutorial, but data structure is different from structure you're triyng to use, can you show us `books` table migration or data structure screenshot?

Comment: Well i'm not using a migration command, i'm using the old database on mysql. It's works fine when I make it viewable on the view.

Comment: So, you're getting an error when you click Delete button? Sid you try to use `Book::destroy($id);`? Also, check `$id` contents by inserting `dd($id);` before all other clauses in `delete` action.

Answer (score 0):

As i noticed you are using resource controller you can try this

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/books/destroy' ,  'method' => 'delete')) !!}
        {!! Form::hidden('id', $book->id) !!}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

In your Controller add the following chunk of code

```
 public function destroy($id) {
    $book= Book::find($id);
    $book->delete();
    return "deleted";
    return Redirect::to('/books');
}
```

Make sure you include `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;` in your controller.

Comment: Yeah, i'll listed `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;` in my controller. Thanks anyway!